# On the series exercise $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\ln n} \ln(1 + 1/n^x)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am studying the series

$$\sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\ln n} \ln(1 + 1/n^x) $$

I have found that the series diverges for $x < 0$ and converges for $x \ge 0$.

Now I would like to study total convergence and uniform convergence, so I take $a > 0$ and notice that

$$ \frac{(-1)^n}{\ln n} \ln(1 + 1/n^x)  \le \frac{1}{\ln n} \ln(1 + 1/n^x)  \le   \sup_{[a, \infty )}\{ \frac{1}{\ln n} \ln(1 + 1/n^x)  \} \le \frac{1}{\ln n} \ln(1 + 1/n^a)  $$

and $\frac{1}{\ln n} \ln(1 + 1/n^a)$ converges only for $a \ge 1$ (taylor expand) so the series converges uniformly on $[a, \infty)$ correct?

But I am a bit stuck on the point $0$, does it converge uniformely also on $[0, +\infty)$?  what could I do?

Comment: You sum divides by $0$ at $n=1$, since $\log(1)=0$. Not really regarding the convergence, but worth noting.

Comment: @vrugtehagel thanks edited.

Comment: What is "total" convergence?

Comment: @zhw Sorry that is a, probably incorrect, translation from Italian. I mean the convergence of $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \sup_{x \in A} |f_n(x)|$.

Comment: show that at least for $n$ big enough, $\frac{\ln(1+n^{-x})}{\ln n}$ is a positive decreasing function of $n$ which tends to $0$, so that your series is an alternated series (grouping the terms by two yields an absolutely convergent series)

Comment: @user1952009 thank you for your answer! why would that help me with uniform convergence?

Comment: uniform convergence is easy to prove (or disprove) on absolutely convergent series

Comment: @user1952009 I apologize, I am a bit new with the concept of uniform convergence. Could you show me the steps?

Comment: your alternated series after grouping the terms is similar to $\sum_{n \le N} \frac{n^{- x-1}}{\ln n} = \mathcal{O}(\sum_{n \le N} n^{-x}) \sim \int_1^N y^{-x} dy $ whose $\lim_{N \to \infty}$ is uniformly convergent on $x \in [1+\epsilon;\infty[$ for any $\epsilon > 0$, but is not uniformly convergent on $x \in ]1;\infty[$

Comment: The series converges uniformly on $[0,\infty).$ See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series converges uniformly on $[0,\infty)$ by Abel's uniform convergence test. This test says the following: Assume $f_1,f_2, \dots$ is a sequence of real-valued functions on a set $E$ such that the $f_n$ are uniformly bounded on $E,$ and such that $f_n\ge f_{n+1}$ on $E$  for all $n.$ If $\sum a_n$ is a convergent number series, then $\sum a_n f_n(x)$ converges uniformly on $E.$

In our problem we have $a_n = (-1)^n/\ln n, f_n(x) = \ln (1 + 1/n^x)$ and so we're good to go with Abel.